# XML Schema - simpleType with inherited attribute List

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb, schema

I have an xml schema that defines the following types

```
<xsd:complexType name="visualElement" abstract="true">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"></xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="style" type="xsd:string"></xsd:attribute>       
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="textElement">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="sa:visualElement">
            <xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string" use="required" />        
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xs:element name="text" type="textElement"/>
```

The issue is that this means we must define a text element as follows

```
<text id="myText" style="Fancy" label="This is the display text" />
```

When what I really want to do is define it like this

```
<text id="myText" style="Fancy">
    This is the display text here.
</text>
```

my textElement Type should extend the visualElement Type as we are generating Java Classes with JAXB to parse the XML. And then using the JaxB CLasses inheritance to handle all visual elements in a similar manner.

Is there a way to structure the schema so that i can achieve the desired XML format while still inheriting the attributes from the visualElement type?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to make the `visualElement` to allow simple content. Then you could extend or restrict it in `textElement`. Something like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="visualElement" abstract="true">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"></xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="style" type="xsd:string"></xsd:attribute>       
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="textElement">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="sa:visualElement"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I think you really have to make `visualElement` containing `simpleContent`, otherwise you can't extend it in `textElement`. But try also:

```
<xsd:complexType name="visualElement" abstract="true">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"></xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="style" type="xsd:string"></xsd:attribute>       
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="textElement">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="sa:visualElement"/>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I don't think this will work, though.

Another option is using `attributeGroup`s. But it won't be the nice inheritance you want.

Comment: Your First suggestion worked. However because we use visualElement for a number of other types as well some of which should not contain a string it still wasn't exactly what we needed. I had already tried your second suggestion it is not valid.

Comment: In hindsight if you think about it, I am wishing for multiple inheritance... which I guess explains why i wasn't getting very far. For the sake of expediency we have stuck with the label for now. thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @PaulHenry You can't have multiple inheritance but you can have aggregation with attribute groups. You can also use the inheritance plugin to make your classes implement a certain interface - which is in combination with attribute groups almost as good as real multiple inheritance.